# Hhvm Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hhvm

I have hhvm installed on my server and it was working perfect until I had restart the server. On the log of hhvm i see this error:

> Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid

I tried to give permission to that file doing

> sudo chmod +rw /var/run/hhvm/pid

bu still that problem occured. I really need to fix this issue but i have no idea what i have to do :(

any help will be really appreciated,

My OS is ubuntu 12.4

Answer (score 1):

If HHVM isn't running, you can just delete that file. The error is saying that it doesn't contain a valid PID, most likely because it wasn't cleaned up properly on reboot so it still has the old PID in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that another service was listening on port 9000.

Comment: @ChrisBurton I killed the process listening on port 9000

Answer (score 0):

Typical launch command:

```
hhvm --mode daemon -d hhvm.server.type=fastcgi -d hhvm.server.port=9000 -c /etc/hhvm/server.ini
```